# How to animate the fill of a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I have a circular CAShapeLayer that I'd like to animate the fill of. I have created my CAShapeLayer as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Filled layer
    CAShapeLayer *filledCircleShape = [CAShapeLayer new];
    filledCircleShape.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    filledCircleShape.fillColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    filledCircleShape.strokeColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    filledCircleShape.lineWidth = 2;
    filledCircleShape.path = [self filledBezierPathWithRelativeFill:.75 inFrame:filledCircleShape.frame].CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:filledCircleShape];

    self.filleShapeLayer = filledCircleShape;
}

- (UIBezierPath *)filledBezierPathWithRelativeFill:(CGFloat)relativeFill
{
    UIBezierPath *filledCircleArc = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat arcAngle = 2 * acos(1 - 2 * relativeFill); // 2arccos ((r - 2rp) / r) == 2 arccos(1 - 2p)
    CGFloat startAngle = (M_PI - arcAngle) / 2;
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + arcAngle;
    [filledCircleArc addArcWithCenter:self.boundsCenter radius:self.radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];

    return filledCircleArc;
}
```

This looks like this:
[image]

I have tried the following to make it animate a path change.

```
- (void)animate
{
    UIBezierPath *toBezierPath = [self filledBezierPathWithRelativeFill:0.3 inFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    pathAnimation.duration = 5.f;
    pathAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)toBezierPath.CGPath;
    [self.filleShapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"path"];
}
```

which kind of works. The shape layer animates but looks like this

[image]

[image]

I want the shape layer to animate like an hour glass, starting at one percentage and then animates down to another.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this using a CAShapeLayer?

Answer (score 1):

The CAShapeLayer is overkill for the fill. It isn't magically going to animate the way you want, and it isn't necessary anyway. Just start with a big square purple view and animate it downwards — but put a mask so that only the interior of the shape region is visible — as I do here (except that I'm filling instead of emptying):

[image]

Comment: I've thought of that and it's certainly the easiest solution but since this is just a playground project I wanted to see if it was possible to get the same result with a shape layer. Is it? :S ("We don't do it because it's easy, we do it because it's hard.")

Comment: One problem is that the shape isn't closed.